# How to sum multi-dimensional arrays based on some conditions?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

```
 $arr = [ [
        '5'=>[
            'BG' => 50,
            'CH' => 60,
            'LG' => 50,
            'MT' => 40,
            'MO' => 80,
            'PH' => 60,
            'GE' =>null
        ]
    ], [
        '6'=>[
            'BG' => 90,
            'CH' => 60,
            'LG' => 60,
            'MT' => 50,
            'MO' =>null,
            'PH' => 50,
            'GE' =>null
        ]
    ],[
        '7'=>[
            'BG' => 80,
            'CH' => 55,
            'LG' => 65,
            'MT' => 50,
            'MO' =>null,
            'PH' => 50,
            'GE' => 55
        ]
    ]
  ];
```

For each id no 5, 6 and 7 I want to sum up the score. CH, PH, MO and LG will always be compulsory to sum up. But after summing up the compulsory items, I want to sum up the other item based on the following condition.
If MO is null, take the best two from BG, MT and GE. If MO is not null or greater than or equal to 0, I want to take the best one from BG, MT or GE.

So the sum up result will look like below:

```
Array
(
  [5] => Array
    (
        [score] => 300
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [score] => 310
    )
[7] => Array
    (
        [score] => 305
    )
)
```

I have tried `foreach`, but I could not solve the problem. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried foreach loop. But did not know to get around the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is more core way to achieve this, please find inline doc for explanation,

```
$keys  = array_flip(['BG', 'MT', 'GE']); // best of how many keys
$Ckeys = array_flip(['CH', 'PH', 'MO', 'LG']); // compulsory keys
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // use to pass parameters to reduce function during call
    $temp[key($value)] = array_reduce($value, function (&$result, $a) use ($keys, $Ckeys) {
        // if mo empty then best of two else best of one
        $bestHowMany = (!empty($a['MO']) ? 1 : 2);
        // fetching best of keys from $keys
        $t           = array_intersect_key($a, $keys);
        // reverse sort and maintains keys
        arsort($t);
        // fetch top $bestHowMany Values
        $largest2 = array_slice($t, 0, $bestHowMany);
        // fetch compulsory values from CKeys
        $t1       = array_intersect_key($a, $Ckeys);
        // sum by merging compulsory and best of $bestHowMany values
        return array_sum(array_merge($t1, $largest2));
    });
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/J8Opk).

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [5] => 300
    [6] => 310
    [7] => 305
)
```

Comment: This gives me the correct solution. However, In my array, I need to check $keys by substring. For example, to check MO, I need to use strpos(strtolower($keys),'O')!==false instead of the full strinng MO. Because sometimes MO can be something like MOab..MOm, etc. The same goes for other keys as well. If you can help modify your answer to my requirements, I would highly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: You should update your question to precision. I am not yet clear for the phrase ‘same goes for other keys as well’ . What does that mean, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can first add all our three arrays, then subtract based on the conditions, and our codes would look like,

```
$arr = [[
    '5' => [
        'BG' => 50,
        'CH' => 60,
        'LG' => 50,
        'MT' => 40,
        'MO' => 80,
        'PH' => 60,
        'GE' => null,
    ],
], [
    '6' => [
        'BG' => 90,
        'CH' => 60,
        'LG' => 60,
        'MT' => 50,
        'MO' => null,
        'PH' => 50,
        'GE' => null,
    ],
], [
    '7' => [
        'BG' => 80,
        'CH' => 55,
        'LG' => 65,
        'MT' => 50,
        'MO' => null,
        'PH' => 50,
        'GE' => 55,
    ],
],
];

$sum_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $arr2) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $key2 => $value) {
        $sum_arr[$key2]["score"] = array_sum(array_values($value));
        $temp = [$value["BG"], $value["MT"], $value["GE"]];
        arsort($temp);
        if ($value["MO"] === null) {
            $sum_arr[$key2]["score"] -= $temp[2];
        } elseif ($value["MO"] != null && $value["MO"] >= 0) {
            $sum_arr[$key2]["score"] -= $temp[2] + $temp[1];
        } else {
            continue;
        }

    }

}

var_dump($sum_arr);
```

Either there is a bug in my code, which is most likely, or I did not understand the `if` conditions right, or less likely the desired output might be incorrect. However, it should not be difficult to debug it.

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score"]=>
    int(300)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score"]=>
    int(310)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score"]=>
    int(300)
  }
}
```